# Bug on Touch Event when controlling Character

Tags: actionscript-3, multi-touch, flashdevelop, touch-event

Hey guys so I've been stuck on this for awhile and thought I would finally ask for some help. So basically I have a character that is handled by these touch events:

```
//setup Listeners when btn's touch begin and end
        btnUp.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, btnUpMouseOver, false, 0, true); 
        btnUp.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, btnUpMouseOver, false, 0, true);
        btnDown.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, btnDownMouseOver, false, 0, true); 
        btnDown.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, btnDownMouseOver, false, 0, true);




private function btnDownMouseOver(e:TouchEvent):void 
    {
        //trace("btnDownRollover");
        if (e.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN)
          {
              //Mouse was pressed on this button
             btnPressedDown = true;

          }
          else if(e.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_END)
          {
              //Mouse was released
              btnPressedDown = false;
          }
    }

    private function btnUpMouseOver(e:TouchEvent):void 
    {
        //trace("btnUpRollOver");
          if (e.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN)
          {
              //Mouse was pressed on this button
              btnPressedUp = true;



          }
          else if(e.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_END)
          {
              //Mouse was released
              btnPressedUp = false;
          }
    }
```

now everything is working fine. When i push the button to move the character up or down they respond perfectly. But the Bug that I am having trouble fixing is when say the person swipes the button to move the character up or down instead of just pressing the button the character flies to the top of the stage and gets stuck i can still control in hardly but the second i release the button it goes flying up or down depending on if the person swiped the buttons up or down. Can you see anything im doing wrong here? maybe i should be using something different like TOUCH_MOVE or TOUCH_OUT? ANy help would be appreciated thank you!